# Добавление вертикальной прокрутки к Text

Tags: qt, qml, scrollview

Следующий код добавляет к `Text` горизонтальную прокрутку (при необходимости):

```
…
ScrollView {
    Layout.fillHeight: true
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Text {
        text: "Some very long text"
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
    }
}
…
```

Что нужно добавить, чтобы включалась только вертикальная прокрутка?

Answer (score 1):

Компонент `ScrollView` имеет настройки

```
horizontalScrollBarPolicy : enumeration
verticalScrollBarPolicy : enumeration
```

со значениями

```
Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded
Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff
Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn
```

По умолчанию установлено `Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded`. В вашем случае надо установить `horizontalScrollBarPolicy: Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff`

Подробнее в [документации](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-scrollview.html)

Добавил код и результат работы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
ScrollView {
    id: scroll
    Layout.fillHeight: true
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    horizontalScrollBarPolicy: Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff
    Text {
        text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..."
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        width: scroll.width - 20    //добавили отступ на сам scrollbar
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. К сожалению установка `horizontalScrollBarPolicy: Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff` приводит лишь к исчезновению полосы горизонтальной прокрутки. Длинный текст просто вылезает за правый край экрана.
Возможно надо ограничить ширину `Text`'а. Но к чему её приравнять?

Comment: Полагаю, к ширине ScrollView. Для этого надо задать для ScrollView соответствующий id.

Comment: Не помогает приравнивание ни к `scroll_view.width`, ни к `scroll_view.flickableItem.width`. Ничего не меняется.

Comment: Отредактировал ответ, добавил код и скриншот того, как это выглядит у меня

Comment: Спасибо, вот так вроде вышло.
Получается, без магических чисел здесь не обойтись никак? (я про вычитание ширины полосы прокрутки).

Comment: Можно еще поковыряться, например, найти конкретно ширину полосы прокрутки без магических чисел, но это выходит за рамки этого вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо, вы правы.

P. S. Странно, вот ListView + ScrollView заработали как надо безо всякой магии.